# Another contract is intercepting my contract calls and stealing the funds, what can it be?

Tags: security, oracles, reentrant-attacks

This is the code I have, and I deployed to polygon mainnet to test. https://polygonscan.com/address/0x3CC3F39cc2386a8847378F4022917B3bB623BAFD

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
// An example of a consumer contract that relies on a subscription for funding.
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/VRFCoordinatorV2Interface.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/VRFConsumerBaseV2.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ConfirmedOwner.sol";

/*
    Depending on the BetType, number will be:
      color: 0 for black, 1 for red
      row: 0 for top, 1 for middle, 2 for bottom
      dozen: 0 for first, 1 for second, 2 for third
      eighteen: 0 for low, 1 for high
      modulus: 0 for even, 1 for odd
      number: number
*/

contract Roulette is VRFConsumerBaseV2, ConfirmedOwner {
    uint8[] payouts = [2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 36];
    uint256[] public entrys;

    bool public isActive;

    event RequestSent(uint256 requestId, uint32 numWords);
    event SpinRequest(uint256 requestId);
    event SpinResult(
        uint256 requestId,
        bool didWin,
        uint256 choice,
        uint256 result,
        address player
    );

    event SpinResultOracle(
        bool didWin,
        uint256 choice,
        uint256 result,
        address player
    );

    struct SpinStatus {
        uint256 randomWord;
        address player;
        bool didWin;
        bool fulfilled;
        BetType betType;
        uint256 choice;
        uint256 entry;
    }

    struct Game {
        address player;
        bool didWin;
        uint256 result;
        BetType betType;
        uint256 choice;
        uint256 datetime;
    }

    Game[] public games;

    enum BetType {
        COLOR,
        ROW,
        DOZEN,
        EIGHTEEN,
        MODULUS,
        NUMBER
    }

    mapping(uint256 => SpinStatus) public statuses;

    VRFCoordinatorV2Interface COORDINATOR;

    // Your subscription ID.
    uint64 s_subscriptionId;

    // past requests Id.
    uint256[] public requestIds;
    uint256 public lastRequestId;

    bytes32 keyHash =
        0xd729dc84e21ae57ffb6be0053bf2b0668aa2aaf300a2a7b2ddf7dc0bb6e875a8;

    uint32 callbackGasLimit = 2_000_000;

    uint16 requestConfirmations = 3;

    uint32 numWords = 1;

    constructor(uint64 subscriptionId)
        payable
        VRFConsumerBaseV2(0xAE975071Be8F8eE67addBC1A82488F1C24858067)
        ConfirmedOwner(msg.sender)
    {
        COORDINATOR = VRFCoordinatorV2Interface(
            0xAE975071Be8F8eE67addBC1A82488F1C24858067
        );
        s_subscriptionId = subscriptionId;
        isActive = true;
    }

    function spinOracle(uint256 choice, BetType betType) external payable {
        require(!isActive, "Disabled");
        require(msg.value > 0, "You dont have funds");
        require(isValidValue(msg.value), "Invalid bet");
        require(choice >= 0 && choice <= 36, "Number is not between 0 and 36");
        uint256 seed = uint256(
            keccak256(
                abi.encodePacked(
                    block.timestamp,
                    block.difficulty,
                    block.number
                )
            )
        );
        uint256 randomNumber = uint256(
            keccak256(
                abi.encodePacked(seed, msg.sender, blockhash(block.number - 1))
            )
        );

        uint256 result = randomNumber % 37;

        bool didWin = false;

        if (result == 0) {
            didWin = betType == BetType.NUMBER && choice == 0;
        } else if (betType == BetType.NUMBER) {
            didWin = (choice == result);
        } else if (betType == BetType.COLOR) {
            if (choice == 0) {
                if (result <= 10 || (result >= 20 && result <= 28)) {
                    didWin = (result % 2 == 0);
                } else {
                    didWin = (result % 2 == 1) && (result != 19);
                }
            } else {
                if (result <= 10 || (result >= 20 && result <= 28)) {
                    didWin = (result % 2 == 1);
                } else {
                    didWin = (result % 2 == 0) || (result == 19);
                }
            }
        } else if (betType == BetType.MODULUS) {
            didWin =
                (choice == 0 && result % 2 == 0) ||
                (choice == 1 && result % 2 == 1);
        } else if (betType == BetType.EIGHTEEN) {
            didWin =
                (choice == 0 && result <= 18) ||
                (choice == 1 && result >= 19);
        } else if (betType == BetType.DOZEN) {
            didWin =
                (choice == 0 && result <= 12) ||
                (choice == 1 && result > 12 && result <= 24) ||
                (choice == 2 && result > 24);
        } else if (betType == BetType.ROW) {
            didWin =
                (choice == 0 && result % 3 == 0) ||
                (choice == 1 && result % 3 == 2) ||
                (choice == 2 && result % 3 == 1);
        }

        if (didWin) {
            payable(msg.sender).transfer(msg.value * payouts[uint256(betType)]);
        }

        Game memory newGame = Game(
            msg.sender,
            didWin,
            result,
            betType,
            choice,
            block.timestamp * 1000
        );

        games.push(newGame);

        emit SpinResultOracle(didWin, choice, result, msg.sender);
    }

    function spin(uint256 choice, BetType betType)
        external
        payable
        returns (uint256)
    {
        require(isActive, "Disabled");
        require(choice >= 0 && choice <= 36, "Number is not between 0 and 36");
        require(msg.value > 0, "You dont have funds");
        require(isValidValue(msg.value), "Invalid bet");
        uint256 requestId = requestRandomWords();

        statuses[requestId] = SpinStatus({
            randomWord: 0,
            player: msg.sender,
            didWin: false,
            fulfilled: false,
            choice: choice,
            betType: betType,
            entry: msg.value
        });

        emit SpinRequest(requestId);

        return requestId;
    }

    function requestRandomWords() internal returns (uint256 requestId) {
        requestId = COORDINATOR.requestRandomWords(
            keyHash,
            s_subscriptionId,
            requestConfirmations,
            callbackGasLimit,
            numWords
        );
        requestIds.push(requestId);
        lastRequestId = requestId;

        emit RequestSent(requestId, numWords);
        return requestId;
    }

    function fulfillRandomWords(
        uint256 _requestId,
        uint256[] memory _randomWords
    ) internal override {
        uint256 result = _randomWords[0] % 37;
        statuses[_requestId].fulfilled = true;

        if (result == 0) {
            statuses[_requestId].didWin = (statuses[_requestId].betType ==
                BetType.NUMBER &&
                statuses[_requestId].choice == 0);
            statuses[_requestId].fulfilled = true;
        } else {
            if (statuses[_requestId].betType == BetType.NUMBER) {
                statuses[_requestId].didWin = (statuses[_requestId].choice ==
                    result); /* bet on number */
            } else if (statuses[_requestId].betType == BetType.COLOR) {
                if (statuses[_requestId].choice == 0) {
                    if (result <= 10 || (result >= 20 && result <= 28)) {
                        statuses[_requestId].didWin = (result % 2 == 0) && (result != 19);
                    } else {
                        statuses[_requestId].didWin = (result % 2 == 1);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (result <= 10 || (result >= 20 && result <= 28)) {
                        statuses[_requestId].didWin = (result % 2 == 1);
                    } else {
                        statuses[_requestId].didWin = (result % 2 == 0) || (result == 19);
                    }
                }
            } else if (statuses[_requestId].betType == BetType.MODULUS) {
                if (statuses[_requestId].choice == 0)
                    statuses[_requestId].didWin = (result % 2 == 0); /* bet on even */
                if (statuses[_requestId].choice == 1)
                    statuses[_requestId].didWin = (result % 2 == 1); /* bet on odd */
            } else if (statuses[_requestId].betType == BetType.EIGHTEEN) {
                if (statuses[_requestId].choice == 0)
                    statuses[_requestId].didWin = (result <= 18); /* bet on low 18s */
                if (statuses[_requestId].choice == 1)
                    statuses[_requestId].didWin = (result >= 19); /* bet on high 18s */
            } else if (statuses[_requestId].betType == BetType.DOZEN) {
                if (statuses[_requestId].choice == 0)
                    statuses[_requestId].didWin = (result <= 12); /* bet on 1st dozen */
                if (statuses[_requestId].choice == 1)
                    statuses[_requestId].didWin = (result > 12 && result <= 24); /* bet on 2nd dozen */
                if (statuses[_requestId].choice == 2)
                    statuses[_requestId].didWin = (result > 24); /* bet on 3rd dozen */
            } else if (statuses[_requestId].betType == BetType.ROW) {
                if (statuses[_requestId].choice == 0)
                    statuses[_requestId].didWin = (result % 3 == 0); /* bet on top row */
                if (statuses[_requestId].choice == 1)
                    statuses[_requestId].didWin = (result % 3 == 2); /* bet on middle row */
                if (statuses[_requestId].choice == 2)
                    statuses[_requestId].didWin = (result % 3 == 1); /* bet on bottom row */
            }
        }

        if (statuses[_requestId].didWin) {
            payable(statuses[_requestId].player).transfer(
                statuses[_requestId].entry *
                    payouts[uint256(statuses[_requestId].betType)]
            );
        }

        Game memory newGame = Game(
            statuses[_requestId].player,
            statuses[_requestId].didWin,
            result,
            statuses[_requestId].betType,
            statuses[_requestId].choice,
            block.timestamp * 1000
        );

        games.push(newGame);

        emit SpinResult(
            _requestId,
            statuses[_requestId].didWin,
            statuses[_requestId].choice,
            result,
            statuses[_requestId].player
        );
    }

    function getSpinStatus(uint256 requestId)
        public
        view
        returns (SpinStatus memory)
    {
        return statuses[requestId];
    }

    function toggleActive() public onlyOwner {
        isActive = !isActive;
    }

    function isValidValue(uint256 value) internal view returns (bool) {
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < entrys.length; i++) {
            if (entrys[i] == value) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    function addValue(uint256 value) public onlyOwner {
        entrys.push(value);
    }

    function removeValue(uint256 value) public onlyOwner {
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < entrys.length; i++) {
            if (entrys[i] == value) {
                delete entrys[i];
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    function deposit() public payable onlyOwner {
        uint256 amount = msg.value;
        require(amount > 0, "need greater than 0");
    }

    function withdraw(uint256 amount) public onlyOwner {
        payable(msg.sender).transfer(amount);
    }

    function getAllGames() public view returns (Game[] memory) {
        return games;
    }
}
```

then there's this contract, that are intercepting not only mine, but others, and stealing its funds. https://polygonscan.com/address/0x16e41af5e034113802d06064fbeb020cc3d47b19

The point of curiosity is: I'm sending contract calls through web3.js. My computer is not tempered, but when I check my contract, the fraud contract is the msg.sender. How could this be?
Could it be an breach in the oracle?

Comment: Can you provide a transaction hash where what you're describing happens?

Answer (score 1):

Ignore my comment, i went out and found the transactions you're talking about. Didnt check too deep but i assume they're all calling the `spinOracle()` function (which is the one that doesn't use an oracle, wierdly enough, when `spin()` does). It generates its randomness that way.

```
        uint256 seed = uint256(
            keccak256(
                abi.encodePacked(
                    block.timestamp,
                    block.difficulty,
                    block.number
                )
            )
        );
        uint256 randomNumber = uint256(
            keccak256(
                abi.encodePacked(seed, msg.sender, blockhash(block.number - 1))
            )
        );
```

There are 2 big issues with that approach.

1. You're using public info to get your randomness. Blockhash(block.number - 1) can be known when sending the transaction, block.number too, obviously, block.timestamp can be estimated (reduced to a short range, at least) and block.difficulty returns a constant 22 on polygon (the concept of difficulty itself doesn't make sense on PoS chains).

2. You're settling the bet in the transaction where it's being created, that allows for a check-result attack. Let me explain. We know that if we win, our balance will be greater after the transaction than before the transaction, so we can create a contract that does (this is pseudocode, but it's just to showcase the idea)

```
contract Attacker {
  function thxForTheMoney() {
    uint balanceBefore = address(this).balance;
    Roulette.spinOracle(){value: 10 ether};
    require(address(this).balance > balanceBefore, 'we lost, lets just cancel the bet');

  }
}
```

That would revert the transaction if it loses a bet, making losing a bet only cost gas, and not the actual amount betted.

Comment: With this type of attack is there any way for the attacker to intercept the transaction? Because the player plays, but in the event the attacker's contract is saved instead of the player's wallet

Comment: That's not possible. Can you show me some transactions where you think that is happening?